# Nested resource without namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I namespaced my `registrations` controller to avoid conflict with the Devise controller of the same name.

I have an `invoices` controller, where an invoice model is a child of a registration.
I don't want to namespace the invoices controller. Is it possible to nest the urls without applying the parent's namespace to the child controller?

```
  namespace :ssa do
    resources :registrations do
      resources :invoices, shallow: true
    end
  end
```